# How can I count total likes?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I added a like button to my blog. It's working perfectly but I can't count the total number of likes present. What should I do now? How can I count the total number of likes?

***models.py:***

```
class FAQ(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,default=None, related_name="faqLIKES")
```

***views.py:***

```
def index(request):
    allFAQ =  FAQ.objects.all()
    context = {"allFAQ":allFAQ}
    return render(request,'0_index.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

FAQ.objects.annotate(number_of_likes=Count('likes'))
```

The `FAQ` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.number_of_likes`. In the template you thus can enumerate over the `FAQ` objects, and render `{{ faq.number_of_likes }}` with `faq` a `FAQ` object.

Answer (score 2):

Use [count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#count).

```
>>> post.likes.count() # returns a count of all likes
```

Also, as a side note - why do you have a url parameter if you're getting the id of the post to like inside the POST data? Why not only use the url parameter? You wouldn't have to send any form data from the client side.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: You're not really giving me much to work with here. Can you elaborate how it's not working? Are you calling the count function in a template? If so, provide the code.